# SwiftUI Table do not refresh when data is returned by a function

Tags: swift, swiftui

## Problem

In my budget app, I need to map the NSFetchResult to calculate the balance for each account entry.

```
public func fetchTransactionEntry(account: Account, month: Int, year: Int) -> [TransactionEntry] {
    do {
        let entries = try transactionEntryManager.fetchAll(account: account, year: year, month: month)
        let balance = fetchBalance(account, month: month, year: year)
        let total = Total(balance: balance)
        return entries.map({total.update(entry: $0)})
    }
    catch {
        fatalError()
    }
}

class Total {
    var total: Double = 0.0

    init(balance: Double) {
        total = balance
    }

    ///
    /// Calulate current total and update the `TransactionEntry.total`.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - entry: The transaction entry to update.
    func update(entry: TransactionEntry) -> TransactionEntry {
        if entry.credit {
            total = total + entry.amount
        }
        else {
            total = total - entry.amount
        }
        entry.total = total
        return entry
    }
}
```

I removed some UI stuff. There is buttons to add, update and delete entries.
Because I'm using a function to get the entries, Table will not know when to refresh if transactions are added, updated or deleted in the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

```
struct AccountView: View {
    @State var selectedTransactionEntry: TransactionEntry.ID?

    var body: some View {
        Table(fetchTransactionEntry(account: account, month: month, year: year), selection: $selectedTransactionEntry) {
            TableColumn("Date") { entry in
                Text(DateTool.formatter.string(from: entry.transaction!.date!))
            }
            TableColumn("Description") { entry in
                Text("\(entry.transaction!.details!)")
            }
            TableColumn("Category") { entry in
                Text("\(entry.account!.name!)")
            }
            TableColumn("Credit") { entry in
                if entry.credit {
                    Text("\(entry.amount as NSNumber, formatter: DoubleTool.formatter)")
                }
            }
            TableColumn("Debit") { entry in
                if !entry.credit {
                    Text("\(entry.amount as NSNumber, formatter: DoubleTool.formatter)")
                }
            }
            TableColumn("Total") { entry in
                Text("\(entry.total as NSNumber, formatter: DoubleTool.formatter)")
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 210)
    }
}
```

Please, can you help me to find a good way to fix this?

Comment: Have a look at this link, it gives you examples of how to manage data in your app:  
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot see nothing about updating a value without using a method :-(

Comment: I reverted back the way to get my data by using `@FetchRequest` in the `Table`. Now everything is refreshing. But there is no totals calculated, as expected. How can I calculate the total for each transaction without saving it in the DB?